# How can I trigger validation to occur on jQuery UI datepicker once a date has been selected?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, datepicker

I have some client-side validation that checks to ensure that the `EndDate` is greater than or equal to `StartDate`.  The validation works, but it's not firing as I would like it to.  I would like it to fire as soon as a date is selected on the datepicker for `EndDate`.  How can I accomplish this?  I've tried the following:

Datepicker code:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onClose: function () {
        $(this).focusout();
    }
});
```

Validation code:

```
$("#EndDate").focusout(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('datetimegreaterthanorequal', function (value, element, params) {
        var startDateValue = $(params.element).val();

        return Date.parse(value) >= Date.parse(startDateValue);
    }, '');

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('datetimegreaterthanorequal', ['startdate'], function (options) {
        var prefix = options.element.name.substr(0, options.element.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1),
            other = options.params.startdate,
            fullOtherName = appendModelPrefix(other, prefix),
            element = $(options.form).find(':input[name=' + fullOtherName + ']')[0];

        options.rules['datetimegreaterthanorequal'] = {
            element: element
        };
        if (options.message) {
            options.messages['datetimegreaterthanorequal'] = options.message;
        }
    });

    function appendModelPrefix(value, prefix) {
        if (value.indexOf('*.') === 0) {
            value = value.replace('*.', prefix);
        }
        return value;
    }
})
```

Comment: have you tried the `onSelect:` event?

Comment: Yes I have.  Something strange I'm noticing is that when I place an alert inside of my validation, it seems to be firing just fine when I pick a date, but the validation no longer works?  The validation works fine if I remove the `focusout` portion, but it doesn't fire off how I want it to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are assigning the validators inside of our `.focusout()` event.  Remove that block completely as you want them assigned only once.

You can easily trigger validation on the `onSelect` option like the following:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function () {
        $("#myForm").valid();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Although the answer from Mark will work, you should note that it will validate the entire form. If you just want to validate the related input field, you would be better off doing:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        $(this).trigger("focus").trigger("blur");
    }
});
```

This fakes the user clicking inside the input field and leaving it again.

Comment: This option works well, because  $("#myForm").valid(); awakes validations for all fields in the form.

Comment: I would say, this is the right answer. Because when the user didn't edit any other controls yet, he might see red warning in those fields, which is wrong.